# What exactly does context represent?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me how on how `isSharp` is in `global context` in the below code. I was following the john's Advanced JS.

http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#24

```
function katana(){
  this.isSharp = true;
}
katana();
alert(isSharp);
assert( isSharp === true, "A global object now exists with that name and value." );

var shuriken = {
  toss: function(){
    this.isSharp = true;
  }
};
shuriken.toss();
assert( shuriken.isSharp === true, "When it's an object property, the value is set within the object." );
```

Comment: Maybe you should read the [introduction to the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) at MDN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In code that is not executed on an object - `this` refers to the global context.

It's a part of how `this` works in a language.

Note - if you use strict mode, which you should - this will raise a TypeError.

---

Reference: ["entering function code"](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3) :

> Else if thisArg is null or undefined, set the ThisBinding to the global object.